# Is the Starbucks menu Turing Complete?

Tags: grammar, theory, state-machine, turing-machines, turing-complete

If we were to interpret the Starbuck's mini-language menu system as some sort of grammar or state machine, would that grammar be Turing complete? A description of the Starbuck's order mini-language can be found [here](http://www.dubberly.com/articles/starbucks-drink-platform.html)

Comment: Is this a homework question? What mini-language? Link?

Comment: Intriguing question, wish I knew what mini-language you were talking about.

Comment: When I say Starbuck's mini-language, I mean the rule system which specifies the order and precedence which adjectives are applied to coffee orders at the Starbucks chain of coffee shops. A full explanation of the language can be found here. [link](http://www.dubberly.com/articles/starbucks-drink-platform.html)

Comment: I only glanced at the article, but am I right in thinking that the described language is finite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It's a finite language, and at a glance it looks regular.

Comment: If it's a finite language, then of course it's regular. I won't downvote this, but you should be careful not to say things that make people wonder about the soundness of your advice.

Comment: It would have been better to say that "It's a finite language, and therefore regular, which is less than what is necessary to be Turing-complete."